# When changing the brightness in linux the whole system freezes

Tags: linux, freeze, arch-linux, brightness

I am currently using ARCH Linux, but I have tested it on other Linux distros too, (on UBUNTU 20.04, KALI LINUX 2019).

**Problem**
When I change the brightness from the keyboard button (My keyboard has dedicated brightness buttons)or the slider in the gnome-shell, then I am able to change the brightness, but if I change it too frequently, then everything freezes. (Here everything means everything, ssh shell freezes too). Then I have to power off by holding the power button and restart.

In Kali Linux and Ubuntu, I don't have to change much for the system to freeze, but in the arch, I am able to change brightness more than in kali/ubuntu.

Though The brightness works fine with windows (7,8 and 10).

My Laptop:

> Inspiron 14 n4030
> Processor: i3-m380
> GPU: (No)

How to fix this?

Comment: I have a very similar issue.